# How to edit/rename "project" link on Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, project, customization, edit

I'd like to rename projects link. By default WordPress makes them appear: http://www.example.com/project/specific-project-name/

I would like to customize the projects URL so that they appear under that ex: http://www.example.com/my-custom-name/specific-project-name/

Does anyone know how to make WordPress to change/display the project page so that the URL would appear as above?

Any input would be great!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just using two steps.

1. Rename your current directory to the new desired directory.

   **Example:** In your case it is from **"project"** to **"my-custom-name"**
2. Go to your database, search **"siteurl"** and **"home"** under the wordpress options(**wp_options**) table and change the respective URLs.

   **Example:** In your case it is from **"http://www.example.com/project/specific-project-name"** to **"http://www.example.com/my-custom-name/specific-project-name"**. Make sure there is no **forward slash(/)** at the end of the URLs.